# Handling an exception in a catch block

Tags: javascript

I have several async callbacks which I'd like to try one after the other.

These are designed to throw an error if the asynchronous test they are running fails.

The tests check the privilege of a user from most to least. So if we're checking that a user is in a particular group, we first check if they are admin, then if they are no further checks are needed.

My instinct was to chain the catch blocks like this:

```
try {
  await userIsAdmin;
  next();
} catch(e) {
  await userIsInGroup(group);
  next();
} catch(e) {
  console.log('User is not admin or in the group');
}
```

I'm about to start nesting my try's and catches but I'm starting to smell a rat.

Is this a sensible approach to sequencing multiple asynchronous operations which may or may not throw an error?

Comment: using `.then()` and `.catch()`

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Isn't [the whole point of async/await](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9) to write async code in the same way as sync code. (i.e.no then/catch chains)?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with .then chains

Comment: @LondonRob could you fix the code with the missing `}` brackets?

Comment: @noseratio Done!

Answer (score 1):

A relatively neat solution, avoiding the `.catch` blocks acting as error handlers to calls to `next()` looks like this:

```
  getUser()
    .then(async () => {
      await userIsAdmin();
      next();
    })
    .catch(async () => {
      await userIsInGroup(group);
      next();
    })
    // etc...
```

This way the catch blocks act unambiguously as error handlers for the `await` statements, and not erroneously for the `next()` call too.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

I'd refactor it like this:

```
if (
  await userIsAdmin().then(v => true, e => false)) || 
  await userIsInGroup(group).then(v => true, e => false)) )
{
  next();
}
else {
  console.log('User is not admin or in the group');
}
```

You can further log errors in the `e =>` lambdas if you like:

```
await userIsAdmin().then(v => true, e => console.error(e)))
```

You could also reuse the `onFulfilled`/`onRejected` resolvers passed to `then` with a spread:

```
const toBoolean = [value => true, error => (console.error(error), false)];
if (
  await userIsAdmin().then(...toBoolean)) || 
  await userIsInGroup(group).then(...toBoolean)) )
{
  next();
}
else {
  console.log('User is not admin or in the group');
}
```

Comment: This is very neat. But I think my solution is more readable. If I came this code in a code base, I'd have to spend a while working out what it does. Think mine is pretty obvious.

Comment: @LondonRob, to each his own I suppose :) I like that `await` allows me to keep the linear structure of the codeflow and gives me an option to use `if` which is more readable to me than callbacks.